# foo.foo: Is giving a table column the same name as the table itself a bad idea?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a very simple table called `genre`, which looks like this:

```
GENRE
=====
id int
genre_category varchar()
```

`genre_category` has values like "narrative", "myth", and so on.

`genre_category` seems like a silly name for the column. The column could be called `genre_type` or `genre_label` or `genre_category`. But it seems redundant.

So, is there any reason not to just go ahead and call it `genre.genre`?

**EDIT:**

The bottom line is that it's better to use `.name`. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're modeling a genre entity. Examples horror, drama, romance. Is this correct?

Would you be comfortable in calling your `genre`'s column `[name]`?

Answer (score 5):

This column should be called 'Name' as this is Genre name.

Comment: Thanks, it seems so obvious now that you point it out. :) Been staring at a console too long!

Comment: @pat - also, I recommend to call it `name`, not to prefix it with `genere`, otherwise all the columns in this table end up having 'genere' prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Why not name the column "category"?  Giving your "genre" table a "genre" column seems to say that your genre has a genre, which makes no sense.  Rather, a genre has a name or type or category or whatever, so you should name it accordingly.

Comment: The reason I don't want to call it `category` is that that column name is being used on other tables.